# With ldd -u, the output is "Unused direct dependencies: /lib64/libc.so.6", but I really use printf()

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, ldd

In Fedora 18, I wrote a file "a.c" like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)  
{  
    printf("a");
}
```

and then I compiled it with gcc 4.7.2 : `gcc a.c -o a`
at last used ldd 2.16: `ldd -u ./a`
The output is so strange:

`Unused direct dependencies:`
`/lib64/libc.so.6`

I think the object file really use `/lib64/libc.so.6` because of `printf()`. And in Red Hat 6,
there is no this strange appearance.

Answer (score 8):

just `ldd -u` doesn't work too well; you are advised to use `ldd -u -r`.

See e.g. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=216864